# Is there a more optimal way to write this jQuery code that adds a _blank attribute to targeted links (opens them in a new tab)?

Tags: jquery, attributes, href

Here's the code I'm working with. Is this the optimal way to write it? Can I do better?

```
// Open External URLs and PDFs in New Tab
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("click", 'a[href^="http"]', function () {
        $(this).attr("target", "_blank");
    });
    $(document).on("click", 'a[href$=".pdf"]', function () {
        $(this).attr("target", "_blank");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the selectors into just one event listener

```
$(document).on("click", 'a[href^="http"], a[href$=".pdf"]', function () {
    $(this).attr("target", "_blank");
});
```

Comment: Yes, this is better, thank you! I tried to do this but added a ' after each ('a[]', 'a[]') and that didn't work so I gave up.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen thank you for answering as well. I didn't see it but I appreciate it.